# How to add Reporting services sharePoint features in SQL Server 2008R2

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, installation

I am facing some issues related to SSRS on SQL Server 2008R2, 
how can we have install below features:

Reporting Services- SharePoint

Reporting Services Add-in for SharePoint Products

Any one could you please help me.

Thanks

Comment: SQL Server 2008R2 has been out of support since July 9 , 2019. I know that SharePoint will have its requirements but it may be worth exploring upgrade to a supported version.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/lifecycle/products/microsoft-sql-server-2008-r2

Answer (score 0):

The Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 Reporting Services Add-in for Microsoft SharePoint 2010 products is installed by the SharePoint 2010 Products Preparation tool (PreRequisiteInstaller.exe). If you want to download and install the add-in separately, the most up-to-date version of this file is available online at the Microsoft Download Center [[1]](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg426282(v=sql.110).aspx)

Download the add-in From https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=622 and follow the instructions

Step 1: Install a SharePoint technology instance.

Step 2: Install SQL Server 2008 R2 Reporting Services and specify that the report server use SharePoint Integrated mode.

Step 3: Configure Reporting Services.

Step 4: Download the Reporting Services Add-in by clicking the rsSharePoint.msi link later. To start the installation immediately, click Run. To install at a later time, click Save.

Step 5: Install the Reporting Services Add-in and configure the report server on the SharePoint technology instance.

Step 6: Set permissions and add Reporting Services content types.

Step 7: Verify the installation.

Detailed version : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/aa905871.aspx

[Known Issues](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff946055(sql.100).aspx#Known%20issues%20with%20SharePoint%202010%20integration), [Another useful link](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2122/integrating-sql-server-2008-r2-reporting-services-with-sharepoint-2010/)